# What does rotate period, bufferlogsize, and synctimeout mean exactly in Winston Azur blob storage? Explanation with simple examples are appreciated

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-blob-storage, winston

In our project we are using winston3-azureblob-transport NPM package to store Application logs to blob storage.
However due to increase in users we are getting an error "409 - ClientOtherError - BlockCountExceedsLimit|The committed block count cannot exceed the maximum limit of 50,000 blocks".

Could anyone tell us using  **rotatePeriod**, **bufferLogSize** and **syncTimeout** helps us to stop the error "409 - ClientOtherError - BlockCountExceedsLimit|The committed block count cannot exceed the maximum limit of 50,000 blocks".

Also provide any another alternative solution. However Winston logger should not be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

The error ***"The committed block count cannot exceed the maximum limit of 50,000 blocks"*** usually occurs when the maximum limits are exceeded.

Each block in a block blob can be a **different size.** Based on the [Service version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block#remarks) you are using, maximum blob size differs.

If you attempt to upload a block that is larger than maximum limit your service version is supporting, the service returns status code `409(ClientOtherError - BlockCountExceedsLimit)`. The service also returns additional information about the error in the response, including the maximum block size permitted in bytes.

> - **rotatePeriod:** A moment format *ex : YYYY-MM-DD will generate blobName.2022.03.29*
> - **bufferLogSize:** A minimum number of logs before sync the blob, *set to 1 if you want sync at each log.*
> - **syncTimeout:** The maximum time between two sync, *set to zero if you don't want.*

For more in detail, please **refer** this link:

[GitHub - agmoss/winston-azure-blob: NEW winston transport for azure blob storage](https://github.com/agmoss/winston-azure-blob) by Andrew Moss agmoss